# *.tar.gz backup growing

Tags: linux, shell-script, backup, tar, gzip

I am doing a daily `*.tar.gz`-backup of `graphite whisper` databases (`/var/lib/graphite`) by using [this script](https://github.com/frdmn/tar-multibackup). The backup destination is a windows share mounted before doing the backup with `CIFS`.

The script starts daily at 3AM via cronjob.

Mysteriously the `*.tar.gz-files` are growing by ~12MB daily though the size of the actual directory does not change.

Check the screenshot below. You can see backup from 5 days (30.09.21017 to 04.10.2017) as packed `*.tar.gz` with growing size, the decompressed *.tar-archive as well as the unpacked folders with the size staying the same.

[image]

I think it has something to do with the time while packing it but I can not figure out what is the issue. Furthermore, I am backing up a few other directories (e.g.: `/etc/phpMyAdmin`) and they do not grow. It is only the `/var/lib/graphite` backup that is growing.

```
$ uname -a
Linux ******** 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.43-2+deb8u2 (2017-06-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I hope you understand my problem and someone can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: to get directory size / disk usage, use command `du <dirname>`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I do not know how this should help solving my problem. Or was it a question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Graphite
documentation](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/whisper.html),
"Whisper is a fixed-size database", which explains why your
uncompressed files are the same size every day (even though,
presumably, new data is collected all the time). This also explains
why the uncompressed tar archives are all the same size.

The reason why the compressed archives grow in size is probably that,
as actual data is written into Whisper files, it replaces what were
previously zeros, making those files less compressible.

It looks like you are, in fact, creating about 12MB of actual data
every day, and should expect your archives to grow in the same way,
until the retention settings kick in and start aggregating older data
points. At this point, the size of your compressed archives should
stop growing.

If you want to check for that, you can search for the largest files
from your archives, and see how well they compress individually (using
gzip).

Comment: OK, I got it! Thank you very much, I realy appreciate this!